# how to create search and filter form generating "plus" symbols in url in between category names?

Tags: search, forms

How to create search and filter form to use multiple categories and tags checkboxes? I'm tried to do it standard way, but it gives me wrong filter results

```
&categories=vitamins&types=gainers&types=boosters
```

instead of

```
cat/minerals+vitamins/?types=boosters+gainers
```

which is working well..